# circular buffer which reconfigure existent objects instead of replacing them?

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I was considering to use boost circular_buffer. From [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html):

> In order to achieve maximum efficiency, the circular_buffer stores its elements in a contiguous region of memory, which then enables:
>
> Use of fixed memory and no implicit or unexpected memory allocation.

But I supposed to use circular_buffer calling `cb.push_back(myObj)`. To make this call I have to instatiate this object. When I call `push_back` my new object replace the old, outdated object from circular_buffer.

So while using circular_buffer I do intensive allocate memory, because I have to instatiate new object for every `push_back`.

But I really want to avoid new objects instatiation. Instead I want to "reconfigure" objects from `circular_buffer`. If it is possible? Can you suggest circular-buffer which allows to reuse objects inside it so avoiding expensive runtime memory allocations?

Comment: Why does it have to be a circular buffer?

Comment: The C++11 concept of _rvalue references_ (as a form of moving data instead of copying) basically solves this, if the container supports them (like the rvalue reference form of `std::vector::push_back`). Unfortunately, it seems not to be the case for the boost `circular_buffer` (no rvalue reference support).

Comment: @CareyGregory circular buffers are useful for different kind of things. I'm using it for processing udp multicast datagrams.

Comment: I understand they're useful for certain situations.  I was wondering what made them the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If your objects are sufficiently expensive to instantiate, you could preallocate a pool of them and then put `shared_ptr`s to the pooled objects into the circular buffer to reuse them.

Comment: i'm not sure how can this be used. do you rememnber that i do not need circular buffer for itself? i'm using it to transfer data from one thread to another at low latency.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want a circular *iterator* rather than a circular *buffer*.
Fill a fixed length buffer with default constructed elements.
Then as you fill elements (through the circular iterator) you can just modify the structures instead of copying over.

For an example of a circular iterator, check the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616643/is-there-a-standard-cyclic-iterator-in-c).

Comment: i'm not sure how to use iterator for transferring items from one thread to another