# C++ "periodic" iterator over the custom container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I have a class that contains the vector of elements of the specific class. The main idea is to generate periodic sequence of the elements, based on the one period of the sequence (`elems_`) and the number of the periods (`nperiod_`) so I do not need to store all elements, but just one period.

```cpp
class PeriodicContainer
{
private:
  std::vector<Class> elems_; // elements
  size_t nperiod_; // period of repetition of elems_
public:
  PeriodicContainer();
  PeriodicContainer(const std::vector<Class>& elems, size_t nperiod);
  /*...*/
}
```

Is it possible to implement custom iterator for the `PeriodicContainer` so that I can do things like (semi-pseudo-code):

```
PeriodicContainer container({Class(1), Class(2)}, 4);
for (auto it : container)
  std::cout << it << '\n';
```

and the output will be

```
Class(1)
Class(2)
Class(1)
Class(2)
Class(1)
Class(2)
Class(1)
Class(2)
```

Comment: You could adapt any *RandomAccessIterator* to behave like this. Just check in the `++` operator you reached the end and go back to the start in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standard cyclic iterator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616643/is-there-a-standard-cyclic-iterator-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your underlying container is simply a `std::vector`, then you know that it's a contiguous container -- which actually makes this quite easy.

You can form an iterator from the following:

- A pointer (or reference) to the container being iterated, and
- The current iteration count (note: not 'index'). This will be used as "index" into the underlying container's `operator[]` after wrapping around the container's `size()`.

The behavior of this iterator would be simply:

- Each increment just increments the current count
- Each dereference returns `(*elems_)[current_ % elems_->size()]`, which will account for the loop-around for the "period".
- The `begin()` would simply return an iterator with a `0` count, and
- The `end()` would return an iterator with a count of `elems_.size() * nperiod_`

An example of what this could look like as a [`LegacyForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) is the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class PeriodicContainerIterator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
 
    PeriodicContainerIterator(std::vector<T>* elems, std::size_t current)
        : elems_{elems},
          current_{current}
    {}

    reference operator*() {
        return (*elems_)[current_ % elems_->size()]
    }
    pointer operator->() {
        return &(*elems_)[current_ % elems_->size()];
    }
    PeriodicContainerIterator& operator++() const {
        ++current_;
        return (*this);
    }
    PeriodicContainerIterator operator++(int) const {
        auto copy = (*this);
        ++current_;
        return copy;
    }
 
    bool operator==(const PeriodicContainerIterator& other) const {
        return current_ == other.current_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const PeriodicContainerIterator& other) const {
        return current_ != other.current_;
    }
    
private:
    std::vector<T>* elems_;
    std::size_t current_;
};
```

The container would then define `begin()` and `end()` as:

```cpp
PeriodicContainerIterator<Class> begin() {
    return PeriodicContainerIterator<Class>{&elems_, 0};
}
PeriodicContainerIterator<Class> end() {
    return PeriodicContainerIterator<Class>{&elems_, elems_->size() * nperiod_};
}
```

You could easily make this all the way up to a [`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), but this requires a lot of extra functions which will bulk this answer.

---

If you don't specifically need this as an *iterator* but just want a simple way to visit each element in the periodic sequence, it might be easier to read / understand if you were to make this into a `for_each`-like  call that expects a callback instead. For example:

```cpp
template <typename Fn>
void forEach(Fn&& fn)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < nperiod_; ++i) {
        for (auto& e : elems_) {
            fn(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows for use like:

```cpp
container.forEach([&](auto& e){
    // 'e' is each visited element
});
```

Comment: How would you implement this for a custom container though instead of specifically for `std::vector`? OP specifically put *custom container* in the title. It would make more sense basing the implementation off of a *RandomAccessIterator* which would then work for any container that provides one. On a side note, you should take a `std::vector<T>&` in your constructor and then turn that into a pointer. You don't want to accept nullable parameters, so why not use a reference?

Comment: This _is_ an iterator for the custom container -- it's written specifically based around the implementation of the `PeriodicContainer`, which is what is asked. Iterators that work over their underlying containers are often tightly coupled. As for the reference vs parameter point: that's a matter of opinion. The pointer is not meant to imply nullability, it's meant to be more readable at the call-site that this is capturing the non-owning lifetime of the object (e.g. `&elems_` instead of `elems_`, which isn't as easily readable for lifetime capturing)

Comment: Now I understand your approach. It seems counter-intuitive to implement a concept as generic as a periodic iterator in such a specific way that it only works for a single class. But I guess that keeps this example simple. As for the pointers vs reference conventions, a pointer is technically always nullable which always leads to the question whether you can pass `nullptr`. Other than that this argument really is opinion-based and not worth discussing.

Comment: Many-many thanx! I will definetely use it in my code. Actually, I wanted to do something like this but decided ask here  because of lack of experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use range-v3, you can do:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;    

std::vector<Class> Container { Class(1), Class(2) };

for (auto it : rv::repeat_n(Container, 4) | rv::join)
    std::cout << it;
```

and not have to write any additional code yourself. This will also work for any contiguous container, not just `std::vector`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T1rWj1).