# What type has a variable containing a range to be?

Tags: variables, types, programming-languages, range, ada

A *for loop* can be done in *Ada* using a range with a start and an end point:

```
for I in 0..10 loop
(...)
end loop;
```

I know, it's possible doing the *for loop* using two variables describing the range:

```
for I in range_start..range_end loop
(...)
end loop;
```

Is it also possible to store the range in **one** variable?, like:

```
for I in my_range loop
(...)
end loop;
```

Which type has the variable *my_range* to be?

Edit:
Let's say I want to use this variable as a parameter in a subprogram: So the subprogram has this loop which iterates over the range. 
I'd rather use two variables describing the range instead of using generics, because generics would cause in higher effort. But I think using one variable describing the range would cause in a higher readability, that's why I'm asking that question.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is an array, then you can iterate over its range via:

```
for I in Arr_Var'Range loop
   ...
end loop;
```

If you're interested in iterating over the elements of a container, e.g. array, vector, map, etc., and don't care about the index, you can use [generalized looping](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5-2.html) (Ada 2012 only):

```
for Elem of Container loop
   ...
end loop;
```

Comment: The variable isn't an array. But I could use a dummy array for the range, right?

Comment: Well, you could, but having a bogus array just for that would be highly discouraged. I edited my answer to add a brief example on how to do this with the First and Last attributes if the variable is of a discrete type.

Comment: @Marc, `'First` & `'Last` can't be applied to simple variables - only [arrays & (sub)types](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-K-2.html#p66).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `range` type, something along these lines:

```
type Range_Type is range -5 .. 10;
...
for A in Range_Type loop
```

See the complete example in [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/range#Working_demo).

Comment: But if I'd like to use the range as a parameter for a subprogram I had to use generics, right? So I think this solution makes it more complicated than using two variables...

Comment: A range is a type like any other, you either pass along the range or pass along the two points and build the range where needed

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. It looks like you may be (perhaps unknowingly) a devotee of [Andrei Alexandrescu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838721/c-iterators-considered-harmful). He's argued strongly for languages to make ranges a first-class type, and the removal of "iterators" as a programming paradigm.

It would be interesting to see what an Ada implementation of this would look like. Unless I'm missing something, that's not the way Ada 2012 went.

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu's concept sounds really intresting!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass around an object containing the range, you can wrap Start and End in a record. Inside the subprogram you can locally declare a new [sub]type bounded by the range.

```
type Range_Type is range TheRange.Start .. TheRange.end;
```

Comment: This must be more trouble than creating a generic!

Comment: @Simon : +1 and true. I think I subconsciously slipped into VHDL where generics are more restrictive. The record would at least be portable to VHDL...

Answer (score 1):

My count says you need 4 more lines to create a generic subprogram than a plain one:

```
generic                             -- extra
   type Bounds is (<>);             -- extra
procedure R;

procedure R is
begin
   for J in Bounds'Range loop
      null;
   end loop;
end R;

with R;
procedure P is
   type Rng is range 1 .. 10;       -- extra
   procedure A is new R (Rng);      -- extra
begin
   A;
end P;
```

which doesn't seem so bad.

But, usually an iteration is iterating over *something* (an array, ...): if so, you can derive the iteration range from the thing that's being iterated over.